# VBA copy paste code only returns first hit from specified criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy rows from one excel sheet to another using a criteria. The desired result: VBA code finds all the matches and pastes them without spaces into a table. When a user changes a criteria and hits run, all the old results get removed and new list matching criteria appears.

I have the following code. When I run it though only the first record which matches the criteria appears. HELP! What am I doing wrong?!

```
'Module to search all Wards' records that match a Ward name specified in the drop-down menu

Sub findward()
Dim wardname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer 

Sheets("Ward_rank_table").Range("B7:BC157").ClearContents
wardname = Sheets("Ward_rank_table").Range("B3").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Ward_rank_set").Range("B160").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Ward_rank_set").Select
For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = wardname Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 55)).Copy
    Sheets("Ward_rank_table").Select
    Range("B7").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 55).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

    End If


Next i

Range("B3").Select



End Sub
```

Comment: To give you a more general tip: If you only get one result through a loop, it's probably becaue of one of these reasons: 1. You loop only once 2. You always use the same set of data. 3. Your output is always at the same place and overwrites old output. 4. you exit your loop prematurely

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
sheets("Ward_rank_set").select
finalrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

Comment: unfortunately this correction does not change the listing. it does remove all the data on the right from the wards' name column though:/

Comment: Seems to me like you are not copying correctly. Just put an exit after copy and try pasting to check what you are copying.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the select rather creepy, thus once you do the first copy, you stay on "Ward_rank_table" and you keep on searching on it. Probably there is nothing there, thus it does not find anything.
A working code (and a really bad practise) would be:

```
Sheets("Ward_rank_set").Select
For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = wardname Then
        Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 55)).Copy
        Sheets("Ward_rank_table").Select
        Range("B7").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 55).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

    End If

    Sheets("Ward_rank_set").Select
Next i
```

In general - avoid the usage of SELECT and ACTIVATE in VBA. As much as possible.